# Tidy up PHP echo code

Tags: php

Apologies in advance though I've tried and failed several different things and obviously I'm not a php pro just yet.
I'm looking for a way to tidy up my code here, I'm pretty certain I don't need to continually type "echo" for each line but can't work out how to combine my code to achieve the same result, any ideas?

```html
<?php
$values = get_field('bothscoreno');
$url    = "$values";
$arr    = str_split("$url, PHP_URL_QUERY");
if ($url) {
    echo $arr[11];
    echo $arr[12];
    echo $arr[13];
    echo $arr[14];
    echo $arr[15];
    echo $arr[16];
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more precise?If you want to see what's inside the array you can do var_dump($url) or print_r($url).I haven't understood your question well tho

Comment: foreach ($arr as &$value) {
        echo $value;
    }

Comment: You should give us more information about what the code is trying to achieve, because to me, it looks like there are bugs in the code that need addressing as well as just tidying it up. But ignoring the bugs, you can achieve the same functionality as most of the above in a single line of code.

Comment: Simba your answer has worked flawlessly, thanks very much, sorry for my awful code/adding confusion!

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted probably has bugs, because the way it's written, it looks like it's intended to do something different from what it is actually going to do.

`str_split()` will take a string and output an array of single characters. It looks like you're trying to pass it two parameters, but enclosing them in quotes means it's actually just a single string.

Thus, if `$url` is equal to `abc`, your `str_split()` call will output an array of `a`, `b`, `c`, `,`, , `P`, `H`, `P`, `_`, `U`, `R`, `L`, `_` ... etc.

I don't think that's what you intended.

However, if it is what you intended, then you are splitting the string, only to re-join some of the characters back together again with `echo`. You can therefore can simplify the whole thing as follows:

```
$url = get_field('bothscoreno');
if ($url) {
   echo substr($url, 11, 6);
} else {
    echo "No.";
}
```

If I'm right and this isn't what you actually want to do, then I suggest either editing the question to clarify or asking a whole new one.

Comment: WOW! man thanks so much, this is perfect and I'm blown away with how simple you've made that look! I have so much to learn! Thankyou so much

Answer (score 3):

Use the point as [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
echo $arr[11].$arr[12]
```

Answer (score 3):

use for loop and start index from 14 to echo your result

```
$values = get_field('bothscoreno');
$url    = $values;
$arr    = str_split("$url, PHP_URL_QUERY");
$string = '';
if ($url) {
  for($i = 11;$i <= 16;$i++){
    $string .= $arr[$i];
  }
} else {
    $string = 'No';
}

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

in `PHP` you're able to use a `.` as concatenation operator.

See the code below:

```html
<?php
$values = get_field('bothscoreno');
$url    = "$values";
$arr    = str_split("$url, PHP_URL_QUERY");
if ($url) {
    echo $arr[11].
    $arr[12].
    $arr[13].
    $arr[14].
    $arr[15].
    $arr[16];
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use **array_slice**

```
<?php
    $values = get_field('bothscoreno');
    $url    = "$values";
    $arr    = str_split("$url, PHP_URL_QUERY");
    if ($url) {
        $subArr = array_slice($arr, 11, 6);
        print_r($subArr);

        // Or...
        foreach ($subArr as $val) {
          echo $val;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No';
    }
    ?>
```